# Hashed texts based on user's passwords

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have finished my first project using ASP.NET MVC. I did not have to wait long to realise I have essentially violated all possible codes of good programming. Well, experience comes with practice.

One of the styles I completely missed was Dependency Injection Principle. It was far too late I could re-write the project and apply it.

DI took me some time to understand. Based on this very simple project, I would like experience programmers to give me some reviews, whether I have sorted the DI correctly.

This is a very simple task. I want to generate hashed texts based on password provided by users. I know I could sort this in couple of lines but I wanted to do something I could apply DI.

I split the whole solution into two projects. The first project contains hashing algorithms, the second the main function to generate hashed text. I tried to lose all possible couplings based everything on interfaces.

So, `GeneratePassword.computetHashedPassword()` uses injected object of `HashingAlgorithm` to make `GeneratePassword` independent to it. On the other hand, `HashingAlgorithm` using one of the `System` interfaces, `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm`. This way I tried to make hashing algorithm also independent.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IGeneratePassword gp;
        string password = "propiotr";

        Console.WriteLine("By bew class:");
        gp = new GeneratePassword(new XAlgorithm(new SHA256Cng()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,19}: {1}", "HashedPassword", gp.GetHashedPassword(password)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,19}: {1}", "Password", gp.Password));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,19}: {1}", "Password Salt", gp.PasswordSalt));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

**Hashing Algorithms**

```
public interface IHashAlgorithm
{
    string GetHashedText(string text);
}

public class XAlgorithm : IHashAlgorithm
{
    private System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm sysHashAlgorithm;

    public XAlgorithm(System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
    {
        this.sysHashAlgorithm = hashAlgorithm;
    }

    public string GetHashedText(string text)
    {
        string hashedtext = getHashX(text);
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            hashedtext = getHashX(hashedtext);
        return hashedtext;
    }

    private string getHashX(string text)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] hash = sysHashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hashString = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte x in hash)
        {
            hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }
        return hashString;
    }
}

public class MD5Algorithm : IHashAlgorithm
{
    public string GetHashedText(string text)
    {
        XAlgorithm ha = new XAlgorithm(new MD5Cng());
        return ha.GetHashedText(text);
    }
}

public class Sha256Algorithm : IHashAlgorithm
{
    public string GetHashedText(string text)
    {
        XAlgorithm ha = new XAlgorithm(new SHA256Cng());
        return ha.GetHashedText(text);
    }
}
```

**PasswordEncryption**

```
public interface IGeneratePassword
{
    string Password { get; set; }
    string HashedPassword { get; }
    string PasswordSalt { get; }
    string GetHashedPassword(string password);
}

public class GeneratePassword : IGeneratePassword
{
    private IHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm;
    private string password;
    private string passwordSalt;
    private string hashedPassword;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { this.password = value; }
    }
    public string HashedPassword
    {
        get
        {
            computetHashedPassword();
            return hashedPassword;
        }
    }
    public string PasswordSalt
    {
        get { return passwordSalt; }
    }

    public GeneratePassword(IHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
    {
        this.hashAlgorithm = hashAlgorithm;
        this.passwordSalt = getRandomString(25);
    }

    public string GetHashedPassword(string password)
    {
        this.password = password;
        return HashedPassword;
    }

    private void computetHashedPassword()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.password))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot compute a hashed password for the empty property 'Password'");
        this.hashedPassword = hashAlgorithm.GetHashedText(this.password + this.passwordSalt);
    }

    private static string getRandomString(int number)
    {
        string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        Random random = new Random();
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, number)
                                    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                                    .ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've kind of missed the point in dependency injection a bit but you're nearly there.

```
public class MD5Algorithm : IHashAlgorithm
{
    public string GetHashedText(string text)
    {
        XAlgorithm ha = new XAlgorithm(new MD5Cng());
        return ha.GetHashedText(text);
    }
}
```

Look at that there - you're newing up an `MD5Cng` and an `XAlgorithm` - neither are being injected! You've overcomplicated things a bit here I don't see the point in having a `GeneratePassword` class. `XAlgorithm` looks a bit like an adaptor but again, I think it's all a bit overcomplicated.

Basically, you want to move everything that your class depends on into a constructor argument (which is the easiest form of dependency injection to use). Need a `Random`? Pass it into the class's constructor! The point of DI is to have all your dependent services easily discoverable.

**Other notes**

All methods should be `PascalCase`. `getRandomString` should be `GetRandomString`

`Random` isn't particularly random at all - for this sort of thing you'd be better off with System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.

Autoproperties reduce the amount of code you have to write:

```
public string Password
{
    get { return password; }
    set { this.password = value; }
}
```

is exactly equal to

```
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Neither MD5 nor SHA256 should be used for password hashing. Use a proper algorithm. Especially not MD5.

Comment: To expand a proper algorithm would be bcrypt or pbkdf2.

Comment: Thanks RobH for pointing out some issues here. I definitely missed `Random` in terms of DI. I also agree it is overcomplicated, I have mentioned that, but it still serves to me as a practice or an exercise. Also, thanks guys for pointing at right algorithm :) I've already found sopm usefull texts to read on CrackStation: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). Cheers!

Comment: @RobH Excuse my ignorance please, but what's wrong with a concrete MD5Algorithm implementation of IHashAlgorithm instantiating an instance of MD5Cng? Surely this is _the_ place to use MD5Cng ?